# Is it possible to post multiple Live sensor data to a single Google Spread Sheet?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I made a weighing Machine using an M5 stack. The measured data is being saved in the sheet called, "logsheet" and another sheet (called "chartsheet")to create a gauge chart using that live data. Now, I want to create 60 more weighing machines like this and want to display their live data in a single spreadsheet. Is it possible to create a sheet like this?

This is my Arduino code: (only postvalues funtion)

```
void postValues(float a){

  DynamicJsonDocument doc(capacity);
  doc["sensor"] = a;
  serializeJson(doc, Serial);
  Serial.println("");
  
  serializeJson(doc, buffer, sizeof(buffer)); 

  HTTPClient http;
  Serial.println(http.begin(host));
  
  http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  int status_code = http.POST((uint8_t*)buffer, strlen(buffer));
  Serial.printf("status_code=%d\r\n", status_code);
  
  if( status_code == 200 ){
    Stream* resp = http.getStreamPtr();
    DynamicJsonDocument json_response(255);
    deserializeJson(json_response, *resp);
    serializeJson(json_response, Serial); 
    Serial.println("");
  }else{
    Serial.println(http.getString());
  }
  http.end();
}
```

And My appSpript code:

```
function doPost(e) {
  var postjsonString = e.postData.getDataAsString();
  var postdata = JSON.parse(postjsonString);

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("####"); //sheetName
  var logSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("logSheet") || spreadsheet.insertSheet("logSheet"); //logsheet
  var chartSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("chartSheet") || spreadsheet.insertSheet("chartSheet"); //chartsheet

  sensor_data = postdata.sensor;
  var date_time =  Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 'JST', 'yyyy年M月d日 H時m分s秒')
  var values = [date_time, sensor_data];
  logSheet.appendRow(values);
 //chart
  chartSheet.getRange("A1:B1").setValues([values]);

  var max = 25; 
  var min = 0;  
  var charts = chartSheet.getCharts();
  if (charts.length == 0) {
    var chart = chartSheet.newChart().setChartType(Charts.ChartType.GAUGE).addRange(chartSheet.getRange('B1')).setPosition(3, 1, 0, 0).setOption('height', 300).setOption('width', 300).setOption('title', 'Weighing Gauge').setOption('max', max).setOption('min', min).build();
    chartSheet.insertChart(chart);
  }
}
```

Comment: As long as you are not running over the [quotas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) then it should be fine. What about your script so far is not working?

Comment: @iansedano This script is to run a single weighing machine, but I don't know how to write a program for 60 M5stack sending data to a particular GoogleSheet...Maybe some changes in the JSON data (Arduino program)?? or app script program?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot image the situation about `I want to create 60 more weighing machines like this and want to display their live data in a single spreadsheet.`. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: @Tanaike I am sorry for my English...Till now, I made only one weighing machine that is posting the data on google sheets(previously you helped me in creating this). Now,  my goal is to post data of multiple M5stack weighing machines on that single spreadsheet. So, for posting multiple data, what changes should be done in the app script or Arduino code? And I want to display all the Live data coming from multiple m5stack in a single google spreadsheet.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot still image your goal from your current script and `Now, my goal is to post data of multiple M5stack weighing machines on that single spreadsheet. So, for posting multiple data, what changes should be done in the app script or Arduino code? And I want to display all the Live data coming from multiple m5stack in a single google spreadsheet.`. I apologize for this.

Comment: @Tanaike すみません、日本語で書きます。 今までは、一つだけのM5stackからのデータがスプレッドシートで表示できるようになりましたが、実の目的は、様々なM5stack計りからのデータをその同じスプレッドシートに表示できることです。それをするために、スクリプトやプログラムで何をチェンジすればいいでしょうか。

Comment: Thank you for replying. I can understand about your English. Please don't worry about this. But, unfortunately, I cannot image your current situation and your goal. So I cannot still understand your question. I apologize for this. For example, can I ask you about the relationship between your current scripts and `様々なM5stack計りからのデータ`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229486/discussion-between--and-tanaike).

Answer (score 0):

#### First things to check

- Make sure your web app is deployed to be accessible to "Anyone, even anonymous"
- **IMPORTANT!** Try deploying the web app again with the **Old Editor** - the New IDE has issues with deployment of web apps and sometimes redeploying it in the old editor fixes things.

#### Sample web app

```js
function doPost(e) {
  let file = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  let sheet = file.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  
  let id = e.parameter.id;
  let weight1 = e.parameter.weight1;
  let weight2 = e.parameter.weight2;

  sheet.appendRow([id, weight1, weight2])
  
}
```

Then accessing with a simple POST request with CURL from any machine:

```
curl -d "id=0001&weight1=100&weight2=200" -X POST https://script.google.com/a/egs-sbt095.eu/macros/s/[SCRIPTID]/exec
```

Produces this:

[image]

---

This example uses cURL just to show that now the spreadsheet can receive data from anywhere. Here is another variation of the same POST request:

```sh
curl -X POST "https://script.google.com/a/egs-sbt095.eu/macros/s/[SCRIPTID]/exec?id=0001&weight1=100&weight2=200"
```

Finally, remember to make sure you are redeploying your web app every time you make changes!

Comment: Thank you, sir. I got it. I will try it out!